# css and HTML css style doesn't apply to id

Tags: html, css

I just began with CSS and HTML, and every time I go to my CSS file and try to create a style file for an id it just doesn't apply I don't know what the problem is. and tell me if you have any tips for me because I don't know a lot I started a few days ago.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24252A;
    font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
}

li, a, button {
    font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     align-items: center;
     padding: 30px 10%;
}

.logo {
    margin-right: auto;
}
.nav__links {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav__links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
.nav__links li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.nav__links li a:hover {
    color: #834bef;
}
button {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding : 9px 25px ;
    background-color: #834bef ;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #9a14f3;
}
#title {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Coin Counter</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <img class="logo" src="64x64.png" alt="image not found /:">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav__links" id="nav__links">
                    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="donate.html">donate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a class="contact" href="#"><button>contact</button></a>
        </header>
        <hr>
        <h1 id="title">Coin Counter</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are your sure your stylesheet has been loaded correctly? I mean, is the path style.css really  pointing to your stylsheet?

Comment: everything else works except the id and I don't know why

Comment: do you mean why #title {} from css is not applied to  <h1 id="title">Coin Counter</h1> ? if yes <h1 id="#title">Coin Counter</h1>

Comment: yes I mean why #title {} from CSS is not applied to <h1 id="title">Coin Counter</h1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's working just fine... You have a #title styling which is applied to your  tag (its font-size is 40px and has the 15px padding).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of of typing `#title {}` selector, replace it with `h1 {}`selector.
SO, it will be looks like this:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

But anyway, your code is working just fine.
!You must also take into account writing code with **BEST PRACTICE**. But no problem as a beginner